# Python curl request

Tags: php, python, curl

Im trying to download the stats from http://www.afl.com.au/stats#stats-player-stats
If you open up the network tab and change a round it will load the data using curl.
The name will be something like players?competitionId=CD_S2014014&roundId=CD_R201401402
If I copy that curl request and paste it into a cmd line it will return the json file no problem.

But im trying to use pycurl so I can create a little script to dynamicaly download all the data. The example below works, but when I paste the curl request into the below I cant get it to work and I think its the quotation marks that screw it up, but I can't figure it out.

```
import pycurl
from io import BytesIO

buffer = BytesIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/')
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.perform()
c.close()

body = buffer.getvalue()
# Body is a byte string.
# We have to know the encoding in order to print it to a text file
# such as standard output.
print(body.decode('iso-8859-1'))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: When you say that it doesn't work, what exactly do you mean? Do you get an error message? Do you get a blank file? Does the program just freeze?

Comment: Can you paste the cURL command you use please?

Comment: Show us the actual code, not some example code that is working :/